# C# Process.start opening multiple PDFs unexpectedly

Tags: c#, pdf, process

I have a program that scans in document bar codes and then allows for the user to click on a link which will open up a PDF associated with that bar code.  My program works fine however I am running into a bug(?) in my code where every so often instead of opening the PDF once, the system will open it multiple times (5+) and it doesn't seem to be consistent.  I'm hesitant to rewrite the code completely since it is actually working, it is simply inconvenient to have to close multiple windows.  The method that I believe is causing the problem is below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am not sure where to start.

```
private void dgDisplay_CellContentClick(object sender,   DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        id = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        string ImagePath = getImagePath(id);
        string filename = "";

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            filename = dgDisplay[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            filename = @ImagePath + filename + ".tif";
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                Process.Start(filename);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(filename);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything obvious wrong with your code, but I'd start by trying to determine if the event is being fired more than once, or if the Process.Start call is actually launching several pdf readers. A simple messagebox before the Process.Start call would do the trick.

Comment: You could also set a variable to indicate the process is started, and when checked, skips starting the process if it is already resident in memory.